# geth --targetgaslimit not working?

Tags: ethereum, mining, go-ethereum, geth

My contract creation requires **5633321** gas - more than default block gas limit. I was able to deploy on **Ropsten** network it few times ago: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe90e8920018f8b633620c731c68b63f3ce11dc19f59ddb49401c9e2c9cd1f8c2.

Now i want to deploy modified version with (probably updated) geth version right from Remix connected via to geth as web3 provider.

When running `geth -testnet` without mining arguments Remix IDE reports:

> creation of ... Contract errored: exceeds block gas limit

I've tried to mine the transaction on myself with following:

> $geth -rpc --nousb --ipcdisable --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpccorsdomain "*" --syncmode "fast" --rpcapi="db,personal,eth,net,web3,admin" --cache=2048 --testnet --targetgaslimit "5800000" --gasprice "0" --mine --verbosity 4

and i'm still getting the same Remix IDE error. Meanwhile in geth log i can see:

`DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=1.128698ms
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=585.129µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=585.857µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=586.8µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=572.322µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=556.395µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=586.05µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=591.607µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=593.849µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=558.404µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=559.293µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=725.188µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=698.486µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=593.769µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=705.957µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=886.8µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=993.159µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=612.746µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=594.387µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=551.487µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=643.653µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=583.393µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=588.098µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] VM returned with error                   err="contract creation code storage out of gas"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:53] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=573.148µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:55] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=18.543326462s confidence=0.984 ttl=56.512994931s
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:57] Revalidated node                         b=7  id=38e1eb00a922f0b7
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Transaction pool status report           executable=114 queued=0  stales=16
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=1.029656ms
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=882.256µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=567.244µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=665.415µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=499.283µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=840.601µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=449.378µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=404.487µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=885.109µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=648.022µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=731.928µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=649.778µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=485.086µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=472.941µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=724.858µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=547.733µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=1.340049ms
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=892.869µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=709.442µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=424.299µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=419.544µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=381.663µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=702.104µs
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] VM returned with error                   err="evm: execution reverted"
DEBUG[07-20|12:32:59] Executing EVM call finished              runtime=444.091µs`

BTW Remix IDE estimates gas requirement wrong:

`{
    "Creation": {
        "codeDepositCost": "4072000",
        "executionCost": "65552",
        "totalCost": "4137552"
    },`

i've tried to deploy it with this value and failed:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x092199ab2a8b535aaed5a954ae549ff8dcb78f4985774f6ad2ea6c1143a7c501.

What should i do to deploy my contract on Ropsten network that requires more than default block gas?

PS. geth `1.8.10` synced with `--fast`, account is unlocked, account has enough ether.

PPS. As far as i understand block gas limit is agreed between miners and can't be set for single personal miner instance. So what i'm trying to do will just not work. But how did it happen that the block where my first contract deploy transaction was mined has almost 9.000.000 gas limit? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/3426903

Answer (score 2):

We've been having issues with `--targetgaslimit` too. I just removed that flag and suddenly everything works fine. Considering this post is new, I'm glad someone else is encountering this bug as well. I'll create an issue on the go-ethereum repo on Github.

Comment: i believe it should *not work* without this flag as required gas amount is larger than default block gas limit on Ropsten

Comment: @4ntoine Ah, ok. I didn't see that he was trying to deploy to Ropsten. I assumed it was a private testnet. Yeah, that makes sense.